# arquillian runtime issue from official guide for IDEA

Tags: java, glassfish, jboss-arquillian

I strictly follow the steps one by one from IDEA official guide(https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/arquillian-a-quick-start-guide.html).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPZpv.png)
All the maven dependencies are correct and the version of dependencies are exactly the same as the article mentions. no compile issue. but when I try to run the example code in an embedded container(I use GlassFish Embedded 3.1 which the guide mentions), I got runtime issue:

```
*java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create new instance of class org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:165)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:102)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder.build(TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder.java:52)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:113)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:161)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/embeddable/GlassFishException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.loadable.SecurityActions$2.run(SecurityActions.java:192)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.loadable.SecurityActions$2.run(SecurityActions.java:189)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.loadable.SecurityActions.getConstructor(SecurityActions.java:188)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.loadable.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:157)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.loadable.ServiceRegistryLoader.createServiceInstance(ServiceRegistryLoader.java:103)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.loadable.ServiceRegistryLoader.all(ServiceRegistryLoader.java:55)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.loadable.ServiceRegistryLoader.onlyOne(ServiceRegistryLoader.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerRegistryCreator.createRegistry(ContainerRegistryCreator.java:99)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.bindAndFire(ManagerImpl.java:265)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.InstanceImpl.set(InstanceImpl.java:74)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.config.impl.extension.ConfigurationRegistrar.loadConfiguration(ConfigurationRegistrar.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.start(ManagerImpl.java:290)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.<init>(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:63)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)

    ... 49 more*
```

Is there anyone point out what the problem is? Is there anyone try this and follow that guide? Thanks in advance!Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For what I have seen in the example they are using the managed artifact and you are trying the embedded one, so I suggest opening the pom.xml and add the embedded artifact (Arquillian one and Glassfish one) to be able to make it run.

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQ/GlassFish+3.1+-+Embedded

Also if you want the new way of defining containers is using Chameleon (https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-container-chameleon) Of course both works but later one is easier.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! From that guide, the embedded one and managed one both not work for me. 
I tried your suggestion,for the embedded one, I tried to add it in pom.xml, just as follows:
 <dependency> 
<groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId> 
<artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1</artifactId> <version>1.0.2</version> 
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency> 
then I add a manual container configuration in IDEA, and add dependency manually for the new downloaded jar from maven.
but it still not work.

Comment: Also I tried Chameleon , I also add it in pom.xml,just as follows:
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.arquillian.container</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-container-chameleon</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Beta3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
again, I add a manual container configuration in IDEA, and add dependency manually for the new downloaded jar from maven, it still not work and the runtime exception is the same int my above question.
Could you let me know is there any steps incorrect or missing ?